# Dropdown Menu jumping to the left when toggled (CSS)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hamburger-menu

New member here and also a newcomer to HTML and CSS, I hope you indulge my mistakes.

I have a dropdown menu in CSS (just a burger) aligned on the right, but when I click on it, the burger is on the left. And I just don't know why.

[Menu normal/untoggled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KNL4.png)

[Menu when clicked/toggled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LODRe.png)

Can you help me?
Here is the code:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4%;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  position: static;
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 30;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  float: none;
  /* position: relative; */
  background-color: #FFBB00;
}

.dropdown-content {
  float: right;
  display: none;
  background-color: #1a1a1a6c;
  min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.458);
  color: #FFBB00;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navbar">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropbtn">
            </div>
            <div class="dropbtn">
            </div>
            <div class="dropbtn">
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a href="shop.html">SHOP</a>
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to float right and change the position. I tried text align and all that.
I just want the burger to stay on the same place. That's all.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I made a snippet of your code but we would need more including HTML to help you here.  Don't just post links to pictures but reproduce it IN your question snippet

Comment: The pseudo elements :hover are affecting your layout. Modify your css to either override the Float:none or modify source css

Comment: Please add HTML

Comment: Sorry, added HTML :)